# Simple syntax to setup a post/get request with CouchDB in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, post, couchdb

I am having trouble setting up a post/get request in Objective C for CouchDB. Would anyone be so kind as to walk me through the steps?

Comment: What have you tried? - http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ It is easier to answer a specific question than to provide generalities -- Google has lots of tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This getting started guide](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Getting_started_with_Objective-C) is in the wiki docs for CouchDB.  I can't speak to this specific guide's quality, but the guides for languages that I use were excellent starting places.